# Weak convergence of a sequence and Convergence of Subsequence imply convergence of the sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $T$ be a continuous linear operator.

Let $(u_n)$ be a weakly convergent sequence to $u$, i.e $(u_n) \rightharpoonup u$.

If $T(u_n) \rightharpoonup T(u)$ and $T(u_{n_k}) \rightarrow T(u)$, where $(u_{n_k}) $ is a subsequence of $(u_n)$, does this imply $T(u_n) \rightarrow T(u)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b_n$ go to 0 weakly but not in norm.
Let $(u_n) = (0, b_1, 0, b_2, 0, b_3, \cdots)$.
Let $T$ be the identity map.